# Analytical full-width half-maximum of hyperbolic functions composition

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to find the analytical FWHM of the following function (that I know has a Bell-type envelope):

```
auto[t0_, tau_] := -4 (tau - t0 Coth[t0/tau]) Csch[t0/tau]^2
```

Here is what I tried so far:

**1. Rescale the function to 1:**

```
Limit[auto[t, tau], t -> 0]
```

> (4 tau)/3

```
autoNorm[t0_, tau_] := -((3 (tau - t0 Coth[t0/tau]) Csch[t0/tau]^2)/tau)
```

**2. Try (unsuccessfully) Solve**

```
Solve[{autoNorm[t0, tau] == 1/2, tau > 0, t0 \[Element] Reals}, t0]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

**3. Try NSolve imposing tau=1**

```
NSolve[{autoNorm[t0, 1] == 1/2, t0 \[Element] Reals}, t0]
```

> {{t0 -> -1.35979}, {t0 -> 1.35979}}

**4. Check whether the numerical result scales linearly with tau (it does)**

```
autoNorm[1.3597924763052964` tau, tau]
```

> 1/2

What I need is an analytical formula for 1.3597924763052964` (even if I'm not completely sure it exists), as the FWHM is just 2 times this value.
I tried Rationalize on the number (that clearly didn't work in this case). I tried to play with TrigExpand, TrigToExp, ExpandAll etc before feeding the function to Solve, but it didn't help either.

I expect the number to be some combination of square roots, exponentials and Logs (due to the nature of the input function), but I'm not 100% sure.

Any suggestion is more than welcome!

Comment: Typo in the first line: should be `auto[t0_, tau_] = ...`

Comment: fixed, thanks! :D

Comment: Only approximation: `ArcSec[-3 (3 + Sqrt[2]) + (82 Log[3])/5]`,but analytical formula not exist for you equation.

Comment: Thanks @MariuszIwaniuk ! Could you elaborate on why the analytical formula doesn't exist?

Comment: Just to pick a nit, you’re calculating the HWHM (half-width at half-max), not the FWHM.

Comment: @Roman yes, clearly the number will be multiplied by 2, I'll edit the main post to make it clearer ;)

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation. It's seems  a waste of time and life.`:)`

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

auto[t0_, tau_] = -4 (tau - t0 Coth[t0/tau]) Csch[t0/tau]^2;
```

Verifying symmetry,

```
auto[t0, tau] == auto[-t0, tau]

(* True *)

maxV = Limit[auto[t0, tau], t0 -> 0]

(* (4 tau)/3 *)

autoNorm[t0_, tau_] = auto[t0, tau]/maxV

(* -((3 (tau - t0 Coth[t0/tau]) Csch[t0/tau]^2)/tau) *)
```

Restricting the domain to `Reals`, the exact value for the FWHM point for `tau == 1` is expressed as a [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expression

```
(tfwhm = Solve[autoNorm[t0, 1] == 1/2, t0, Reals][[1]]) // InputForm

(* {t0 -> Root[{-1 + E^(-6*#1) - 
      (-21 - 24*#1)/E^(4*#1) - 
      (21 - 24*#1)/E^(2*#1) & , 1.3\
59792476305296405508513391097477440\
88`20.593565523497226}]} *)
```

Verifying,

```
autoNorm[t0, 1] /. tfwhm // FullSimplify

(* 1/2 *)
```

However, this is not the FWHM point for general `tau`, e.g.,

```
(autoNorm[t0, 2] /. tfwhm) // N

(* 0.833814 *)
```

To find the FWHM as a function of `tau`

```
fwhm[tau_?NumericQ] := Module[{tauR = Rationalize[tau, 0]},
  2*t0 /. Solve[autoNorm[t0, tauR] == 1/2, t0, Reals][[1]]]
```

Plotting the FWHM as a function of `tau`

```
Plot[
 fwhm[tau], {tau, 1/100, 10},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {tau, FWHM})]
```

[image]

Since this appears linear

```
(FWHM[tau_] = ((fwhm[10] - fwhm[1])*tau + 10*fwhm[1] - 1*fwhm[10])/(10 - 1) //
     FullSimplify) // InputForm

(* (2*tau*
  (-Root[{21*Sinh[#1] + 
        Sinh[3*#1] - 24*Cosh[#1]*
         #1 & , 1.35979247630529640\
550851339109747744088`20.5935655234\
97226}] + Root[
    {-5 + (5 + 3*E^(#1/5)*
          (35 + 4*#1 + E^(#1/5)*
            (-35 + 4*#1)))/
        E^((3*#1)/5) & , 13.5979247\
6305296405508580536867166855385`20.\
60205999118258}]))/9 *)
```

Verifying that the result is the same for a larger interval

```
FWHM[tau] ==
  ((fwhm[1000] - fwhm[1])*tau + 1000*fwhm[1] - 1*fwhm[1000])/(1000 - 
     1) // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Since the `Root` expressions are exact, `FWHM` can be evaluated to any desired precision

```
FWHM[1.`50]

(* 2.7195849526105928110103621113550874258460333053779 *)
```

**EDIT:** Since Akku14 has shown that a simpler representation is possible, note that

```
FWHM[0]

(* 0 *)
```

Consequently, the linear equation can be simplified by using the point `{0, 0}` as one of the defining points.

```
(FWHM2[tau_] = fwhm[10]*tau/10) // InputForm

(* (tau*Root[{-5 + 5/E^((3*#1)/5) - 
      (-105 - 12*#1)/E^((2*#1)/5) - 
      (105 - 12*#1)/E^(#1/5) & , 13\
.5979247630529640550858053686716685\
5385`20.60205999118258}])/5 *)
```

Which is approximately,

```
FWHM2[tau] // N

(* 2.71958 tau *)
```

Verifying that this corresponds to a fwhm point

```
autoNorm[FWHM2[tau]/2, tau] // FullSimplify

(* 1/2 *)
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer of @Bob Hanlon inspired me to find an alternative expression for FWHM as a multiple of the fwhm for tau = 1 multiplied with the function value at t0 = tau.

```
fact1 = (t0 /. First@Solve[autoNorm[t0, 1] == 1/2, t0,
          Reals][[1]])/autoNorm[1, 1]

FWHM[tau_] = 2*autoNorm[tau, tau]*fact1*tau

(*   (1/(1 - Coth[1]))(tau - tau Coth[1])* 
     Root[{-1 + E^(-6 #1) - E^(-4 #1) (-21 - 24 #1) - 
     E^(-2 #1) (21 - 24 #1) &, 1.35979247630529640551}]   *)
```

Proof

```
FWHM[1.`50]

(*   2.719584952610592811010362111355087425846033305378   *)

(2*t0 /. First@Solve[autoNorm[t0, 1] == 1/2, t0, Reals][[1]])// N[#, 49] &

(*   2.719584952610592811010362111355087425846033305378   *)

FWHM[11.`50]

(*   29.91543447871652092111398322490596168430636635916   *)

(2*t0 /. First@Solve[autoNorm[t0, 11] == 1/2, t0, Reals][[1]]) // N[#, 49] &

(*   29.91543447871652092111398322490596168430636635916   *)
```

Comment: +1 The proof is that with your definition for `FWHM`,  `autoNorm[FWHM[tau]/2, tau] // FullSimplify` evaluates to `1/2`